# Desktop environment in Ubuntu

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

I have a Dell Optiplex GX270 that I wanted to run Ubuntu 12.04 on, after installing it on VirtualBox it was very sluggish and was using 100% CPU so I switched the desktop environment to LXDE but it installed Openbox and GNOME/Openbox is it safe to remove them is it also safe to remove Unity? If it is safe how would I remove them?

Thanks

Comment: have you installed virtual box guest addon?

Comment: Yes I have installed virtual box guest additions

Answer (score 0):

You may do the below two things:

[1] Go to Startup-Applications from the main menu on the top, and disable all unneeded services such as bluetooth-monitor, sharing-service, etc.

(Sometimes, all startup items are hidden from view by default for security purposes. If that is the case, then issue below command in a terminal, and then open the startup applet:

```
sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

)

[2] Login in Ubuntu-2D mode instead of the default one.

[3] In your virtual machine settings, check how much RAM you have actually allocated to your vm. It also helps to check 3d-acceleration and other settings and disable the ones you don't use.

I'm sure you will lose some of the sluggishness after you do this.

Comment: I have allocated 512 mb ram running on unity 2d but still laggy should I increase video ram an would preload help?

Comment: Try increasing your RAM, I don't think 512 is enough for Ubuntu. To verify, open the system-monitor in your vm and check the actual RAM usage. Increasing video ram won't make any difference unless you are doing 3d stuff.

Comment: I cannot increase my ram as it is half of my physical ram, I did run the system monitor and its using 112 mb ram.